# How to fix exec /bin/sh: exec format error in Azure?

Tags: python, docker, raspberry-pi3, azure-iot-edge

I build and pushed IoT Edge solution, it was built successfuly,  modules reported by device (rpi3), but Azure gives me these errors

`exec /bin/sh: exec format error`

another custom module gives me this error as well

`exec /usr/local/bin/python3: exec format error`

**Dockerfile 1:**

```
FROM python:3.7-slim

RUN pip install -U pip
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir numpy~=1.17.5 tensorflow~=2.0.2 flask~=2.1.2 pillow~=7.2.0 protobuf~=3.20.0
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir mscviplib==2.200731.16

COPY app /app

EXPOSE 80

WORKDIR /app

CMD python -u app.py
```

**Dockerfile 2:**

```
FROM amd64/python:3.7-slim-buster

WORKDIR /app

ADD ./test_image.jpg .

COPY requirements.txt ./
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY . .

CMD [ "python3", "-u", "./main.py" ]
```

Any thoughts on how to resolve these? I'm new to docker.

Comment: Are you building the image on x86 or ARM hardware?  What processor are you running it on?

Comment: ARM hardware, this should be processor: Quad Core 1.2GHz Broadcom BCM2837 64bit CPU

Comment: Are you sure you're running the image on ARM hardware as well?

Comment: I followed tutorial on Microsoft learn and in vs code I have set amd64, like in tutorial...